# Add COLON Character in the Right Edge of the Excel Cell using Worksheet_Change Events

Tags: excel, vba

As we all know the use of format of cell property.

let's say in cell A1, I have typed a number, 15000

Now If I change the format of the cell A1 to the Accounting format, whatever the change will happen, have been seen in the following image within the post.

What happening is actually, when we change the cell format from general to accounting format, it adds one $ character on the left side of the edge of the cell. like below image

[image]

Now, I want to do something else but in reverse direction.

let's say I typed a string value in Cell A1, "NAME"

then after the procedure or function, the cell should look like,

> "NAME             :"

yes, the colon character in the rightmost edge of the cell.

I researched a lot, but I found the false topics only.

Please help me to research with this...this is a very useful feature if we could able to develop.

I know, this can only possible within creating VBA function. and Even in Worksheet_Change events.

Comment: `VBA` is not necessarily needed. If the column only contains text then do formatting the column using the following number format: `;;;@* ":"`. Means: show nothing for positive numbers, nothing for negative numbers, nothing for 0 but if text then show the text (`@`)  followed by as much spaces as fit (`* `) followed by the colon character (`":"`).

Comment: Axel, is there a guide on how to create custom formats? I had no idea you could use custom formats like that.

Comment: @Ricardo A: Have copied [guide on how to create custom formats](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=guide+on+how+to+create+custom+formats&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to a Google search and got [The Definitive Guide to Custom Number Formats in Excel](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel/) as first result.

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you.... your solution works.